I am trying to run Spark on my R Studio in connecting to MS SQL Server with an ODBC Data source but facing issues. What am I doing wrong?
The goal of my current project is to load almost 31M rows of dataset into R studio where I want to conduct Exploratory Analysis and conduct research. I cannot use advanced statistical analysis on just SQL server so I have to use R programming language to complete my research.
So far what I have tried and what works is below fetching records using the odbc package:
library(RODBC)
library(DBI)
library(odbc)

conn <- odbcConnect("Server")

sqlQuery(conn,"USE database1")

df <- sqlQuery(conn, "SELECT * FROM table1;")
close(conn)

But if I change the code for Spark to below :
library(RODBC)
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
library(data.table)
library(arrow)
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
library(SparkR)


# Set SPARK_HOME if not already set
if (nchar(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME")) < 1) {
  Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "/home/spark")
}

# Set JAVA_HOME
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME = "C:/Program Files/Java/jre-1.8")

library(SparkR, lib.loc = c(file.path(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"), "R", "lib")))

# Path to the JDBC driver (assuming Java 8)
jdbc_driver_path <- "C:/AppData/Local/sqljdbc_12.6/enu/jars/mssql-jdbc-12.6.3.jre8.jar"

# Start Spark session with the JDBC driver added to the classpath
sparkR.session(master = "local[*]", 
               sparkConfig = list(
                 spark.driver.memory = "2g",
                 spark.driver.extraClassPath = jdbc_driver_path
               ))

# Function to load data using SparkR:
load_data_sparkR <- function(query, server, database) {
  # Create a JDBC URL using the server and database name
  jdbc_url <- paste0("jdbc:sqlserver://", server, ";databaseName=", database, ";integratedSecurity=true;")
  
  # Read data from the SQL Server using the JDBC URL
  df <- read.jdbc(jdbc_url, query, 
                  properties = list(
                    driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
                  ))
  return(df)
}

# Server and Database for Customer X:
server <- "Server1"
database <- "DB1"

# Load data from Tables:
df1 <- load_data_sparkR("SELECT * FROM table1;", server, database)
df2 <- load_data_sparkR("SELECT * FROM table2;", server, database)

# Show the first few rows of the data
head(df1)
head(df2)

# Stop the Spark session
sparkR.session.stop()

I get a Java runtime error and that the server driver 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver' is not correct what to do?
I am sure Java is running fine on my machine. Any help would be appreciated.

Since you seem to be running on Windows have you tried using backslash path separators instead of forward slashes? i.e.: C:\AppData\Local\sqljdbc_12.6\enu\jars\mssql-jdbc-12.6.3.jre8.jar

What is the exact error you got?
